# formula field displays error in visualforce page

Tags: formula

Below is my visualforce code where 'Customer_Status__c' is the formula field. But this code is genertaing an error which I can't find because the page is displayed on portal force.com site.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!mod.msg.Customer_Status__c}" />
```

Below is the controller code:-

```
 String queryString = 'Select Id,Customer_Status__c,Name,Subject__c,Deleted__c,Message__c,Accepted_Rejected__c,Message_Type__c,Opened__c,Archive__c,Message_Direction__c,Enrollment_Application__c,Enrollment_Application__r.OwnerId,Enrollment_Application__r.Owner.Email from Messages__c where Enrollment_Application__c in : eaIds';
    UnreadMessage = 0;
    UnreadMessage1 = 0;
    List<Messages__c> messageLst = [select id,name from Messages__c where Enrollment_Application__c in : eaIds and Opened__c = null];
    if(messageLst != null && messageLst.size() > 0){
        UnreadMessage  = messageLst.size();
        UnreadMessage1 = messageLst.size();
    }
    if(message_Filter != null && message_Filter.trim().length() > 0){
        if(message_Filter == 'Inbox'){
            queryString += ' And Archive__c = false And Message_Direction__c = \'Outbound\' Order By Opened__c ';
        }else if(message_Filter == 'Sent'){
            queryString += ' And Archive__c = false And Message_Direction__c = \'Inbound\' Order By Opened__c ';
        }else if(message_Filter == 'Archive'){
            queryString += ' And  Archive__c = true And Message_Direction__c = \'Outbound\' Order By Opened__c ';
        }else if(message_Filter == 'Offers'){
            queryString += ' And Archive__c = false And Message_Direction__c = \'Inbound\' And Message_Type__c = \'Offer Letter\' Order By Opened__c ';
        }
    }
    queryString += ' LIMIT 1000';
    listMessage = new List<MessagesModel>();
    for(Messages__c msg : Database.query(queryString)){
        MessagesModel mod = new MessagesModel();
        mod.msg = msg;
        if(mod.msg.Opened__c == null){
            mod.isOpenedBlank = true;
        }
        listMessage.add(mod);
    }
```

Please can anybody give me the correct syntax to display formual field on a visualforce page ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is `mod` and `msg`? You will need to add the controller code so that your visualforce code makes sense.

Comment: What's the error message that's being displayed? Do your portal users have the permissions they need to access the field?

Comment: The line `MessagesModel mod = new MessagesModel();` declares a local variable in a loop - this won't be accessible to the outputField. There needs to be a public variable `mod` with a getter that the outputField uses.